# Solr Could Becoming slow as time goes by

Tags: solr, cloud

We are using Solr Cloud 6.5.0 with 3 server set up.
Server has 62 GB RAM with 30 GB data.
This set up runs fine for some time but after 3 or 4 week it becomes extremely slow.
We restart server it works fine again and after some time it becomes slow again.
I check IO and Load factor on server and everything is fine.
Also when we use same machine with same data in master slave set up there is no issue at all.
Here are configuration stats:

```
solr/nspec 6.5.1  
lucene/nspec 6.5.1  

Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64/nBit Server VM 1.8.0_20/nea 25.20/nb05  
Processors 12  


Duser.timezone=UTC 
DzkClientTimeout=15000  
XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled  
XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark  
XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled  
XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime  
XX:+PrintGCDateStamps  
XX:+PrintGCDetails  
XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  
XX:+PrintHeapAtGC  
XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution  
XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly  
XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  
XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation  
XX:+UseParNewGC  
XX:  
OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50  
XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000  
XX:ConcGCThreads=4  
XX:GCLogFileSize=20M  
XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8  
XX:NewRatio=3  
XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=9  
XX:ParallelGCThrea  
ds=4  
XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m  
XX:SurvivorRatio=4  
XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90  
Xms4096m  
Xmx4096m  
Xss256k  
verbose:gc 

ramBufferSizeMB=200  
maxBufferedDocs=10000  
maxMergeAtOnce=10  
segmentsPerTier=10  
autoCommit  
maxDocs=100  
maxTime=8000  

autoSoftCommit  
maxDocs=25  
maxTime=5000  


maxBooleanClauses=024  
slowQueryThresholdMillis=500  
filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache size="4096" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="1024"  
queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="256"  
enableLazyFieldLoading=true  
queryResultWindowSize=100  
queryResultMaxDocsCached=200
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably the `filterCache`.

- It is fairly large: If you have 20M documents, each entry can be up to 2.5MB, for at total size of 4096*2.5MB = 10GB (and your heap max size is 4GB).
- Your `autowarmCount` is quite high and your `maxDocs`for your `autoCommit` and `autoSoftCommit` is very low: Every time you add 100 documents, up to 1000 searches will be performed.

Set your `filterCache` a low lower (100 or so) and do the same with your `autowarmCount` (10 or so). Also consider if your `autoCommit`-settings can be less aggressive.

Comment: Thanks Toke I am planning to shift auto commit and auto soft commit to 1 minute and 1000 document. Filter cache i was thinking of around 200 and autowarm count of 30. Could you please suggest anything else as read IO piling up on these machines.

Comment: In your original post you stated that IO was fine? Anyway, high IO would be a symptom of very frequent commits (exacerbated by high autoWarm), so I don't see much point in guessing more before you have tried what you describe.

Comment: Sure i will change accordingly and will monitor system. Thanks for your input i will definitely update stats after changes and will discuss them.